# Can i find a 3D function given some points?

Tags: 3d, curves, interpolation

is it possible to find a 3D function given a set of data points? i tried plane-fitting it did not work, too chaotic for a plane.

I am trying to find a 3D equation that cover most of points, how can i get to it ?
Is there some terminolgy for this, maybe something i can study?

points are:

$( 3 , 0.48 , 1.25 )$

$( 15 , 3.77 , 5.5 )$

$( 5.5 , 1.3 , 2.75 )$

$( 12.5 , 3.08 , 5.25 )$

$( 2.2 , 0.1 , 0.2 )$

$( 2.2 , 0.2 , 0.3 )$

$( 2.2 , 0.3 , 0.5 )$

Comment: Short answer; no. You can do a polynomial fit, but this is rather arbitrary. Perhaps the source of your data suggests a certain structure in the points, that may help you find an appropriate equation.

Comment: What exactly do you mean? Do you mean a function $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ such that it has prescribed values at the above subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$? Or are you looking for a function on the plane whose graph passes through the above points?

Comment: @copper.hat exactly. I am looking to compute a function that passes through all these points in ${R^3}$.

Comment: @Servaes I understand what you are saying, but the correct short answer here is: yes, you can find a function. You can even find infinitely many such functions. What you can not do however is find "the one" distinct, unique function (because there is no such thing).

Comment: How is it possible to find any of those infinitely many? @maxmilgram

Comment: Presumably you are looking for some 'nice' function, where 'nice' means something like smooth or satisfies some criteria you are interested in, For example, a function that is zero everywhere except that it takes the above values, for example $f(3,0.48)=1.25$, satisfies the above but is almost certainly not what you are looking for.

Comment: For example, as @servaes pointed out, by a polynomial fit. Generally speaking just crank up the order of the polynomial until you have enough unknowns to satisfy all equations (that come from your points). HOWEVER: this is usually not what you want. If you want a meaningful function you need to do not ANY fit but first  understand where the points come from and THEN do an appropriate fit.

Comment: For example, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_neighbor_interpolation based on partitioning the domain into Voronoi cells.

Comment: @maxmilgram, thank you, i am the one who made the points, and i am here for the appropriate fit.

Comment: I am only aware of Remez methods for approximation on intervals?

Comment: LIke I said, if you want a meaningful answer you need to tell us where those points come from (I guess they are not just some arbitrary points?) and what you expect your function to look like. 
Also, what do you want to do with said function (interpolation, extrapolation, integration, differentiation...)

Answer (score 1):

You can fit anything. You have 7 points. Assume your function is of the form $f(x,y)=ax+by+cx^2+dy^2+ex^3+fy^3+gx^4$. Now substitute your given points and solve simultaneous linear systems in variables $a,b,c,d,e,f,g,$ in seven variables.  If mine choice of $f$ doesn't work, you can adjust $f$ to make the linear system consistent.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at something like a "thin-plate spline" (Duchon $D^m$ splines) for a $3D$ case, or at rbf interpolation.